# returning a pound sign in python(not printing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I have a requirement to return a  price range from function something like 
"£150 to  £199"
but when the function returns the value coverts to "\u00a3150 to \u00a3199".

now I understand that the value "\u00a" is escaped version of £.

but when I print("\u00a3150") it prints £150 I have tried using encoding and unichr(163) but I could not return the value as £150.

Any help is much appreciated.

Just to make it cogent..

```
def price_range(price):  
     print("Print value {}".format(price))  
     return "Return value {}".format(price)
```

So now if I send the value "£150 to  £199" the output is below

```
>>> price_range("£150 to  £199")  

Print value £150 to  £199  
Return value \xa3150 to  \xa3199'
```

Comment: Have you tried `u"\u00a3150 to \u00a3199"` (or `u"£150 to £199"`)?

Comment: Yep but could not get what I need.

Comment: Your code works fine if you print the return value properly: `print price_range("£150 to  £199")`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are just making a confusion between the internal representation of a string and the way it is displayed by `print`.

When you evaluate an expression in interactive mode, Python displays the *representation* of the result of the expression.

Just look this in a terminal using Latin1 charset:

```
>>> t = '\xa3150'
>>> t
'\xa3150'
>>> print t
£150
>>> repr(t)
"'\\xa3150'"
>>> print(repr(t))
'\xa3150'
```

Similarily with you example, you get the correct display, if you print the returned value:

```
>>> x = price_range("£150 to  £199")
Print value £150 to  £199 
>>> x
'Return value \xa3150 to  \xa3199'
>>> print x
Return value £150 to  £199
```

In fact the eval loop of the Python interpretor is close to :

```
while True:
    expr = input(">>> ")
    print(repr(expr))
```

(It is indeed far more complex because of EOF and error processing, but thinking of it that way is enough to understand what happens with your code)